# Making sure that three lists of dicts all have dicts with same values for a specific key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-itertools

I am looking for a way to iterate over multiple lists of dictionaries, making sure that if a dictionary exists with a given value for key 'label', it will be filled into the other lists with a default value (0), as represented below:

```
p1 = [{'label': 201501, 'y': 22}, {'label': 201502, 'y': 11}, {'label': 201503, 'y': 10}]
p2 = [{'label': 201502, 'y': 10}]
p3 = [{'label': 201504, 'y': 1}]

Desired result:

p1 = [{'label': 201501, 'y': 22}, {'label': 201502, 'y': 11}, {'label': 201503, 'y': 10}, {'label': 201504, 'y': 0}]
p2 = [{'label': 201501, 'y': 0}, {'label': 201502, 'y': 10}, {'label': 201503, 'y': 0}, {'label': 201504, 'y': 0}]
p3 = [{'label': 201501, 'y': 0}, {'label': 201502, 'y': 0}, {'label': 201503, 'y': 0}, {'label': 201504, 'y': 1}]
```

If p1, p2, and p3 were just dictionaries, I would use itertools.chain, but I am lost on how to do this with multiple lists of dicts.

Comment: Lists of dicts are not an efficient way to store this data.  Best would be a NumPy/Pandas matrix, assuming your data are fairly large.  Second best might be a list of tuples.

Comment: Are your labels unique? My first approach would be to map your lists into a  dict each, and reverse that in the end.

Comment: @JohnZwinck These lists are being generated by pymssql.conn.cursor(as_dict=True), so I'm just trying to work with the data the way it is returned.  A NumPy/Pandas matrix also would likely not work, as this is being consumed by a Jinja2 template which likely would not parse the matrix object.

Comment: @JohnZwinck while I'm generally all for helpful side comments, to tell the OP his set up is wrong, without further understanding of his situation, is pretty presumptuous.